# Multiple \hypertarget overflow the page?

Tags: hyperref

I want to assign individual anchors to a series of paragraphs with `\hypertarget`, so that each paragraph can be linked to with `\hyperlink`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{t000}{}000

\hypertarget{t001}{}001

\hypertarget{t002}{}002

...

\hypertarget{t100}{}100

\end{document}
```

But the page is overflowed:

[image]

How could I fix this, or what's the proper way to reference individual paragraphs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\leavevmode` before `\hypertarget`.

The command `\hypertarget` eventually issues `\nobreak` and, if it's found after a blank line, this produces a penalty *in vertical mode* that inhibits page breaking.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the insight. I can dig a little deeper now... Maybe LaTeX requires too much insight. :)